# Changing the style of numbers in a javascript clock

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a really simple javascript clock, and i'm trying to change the color and font of the digits, different colors for hours,minutes, seconds. How can i do that? there is no css here.

```
<form action="" name="forme">
    <input type="text" name="clock">
</form>
<script>
    function runTime() {
        var theTime = new Date();
        var hr = theTime.getHours();
        var mn = theTime.getMinutes();
        var sc = theTime.getSeconds();
        var watch = hr + ":" + mn + ":" + sc;
        document.forme.clock.value = watch;
        setTimeout("runTime()", 1000);

    }
</script>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span

Comment: Show your `CSS` and `HTML` too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EJJXRy

---

```
<form action="" name="forme">
  <p>
  <span id="hour"></span>:
  <span id="min"></span>:
  <span id="sec"></span>
  </p>
    <input type="hidden" name="clock">
</form>
```

---

```
span#hour{
  color:red;
}
span#min{
  color:blue;
}
span#sec{
  color:black;
}
```

---

```
    function runTime() {
        var theTime = new Date();
        var hr = theTime.getHours();
        var mn = theTime.getMinutes();
        var sc = theTime.getSeconds();

      document.getElementById('hour').innerHTML = hr;
      document.getElementById('min').innerHTML = mn;
      document.getElementById('sec').innerHTML = sc;

      var watch = hr + ":" + mn + ":" + sc;
        document.forme.clock.value = watch;
        setTimeout("runTime()", 1000);

    }
runTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't (easily/reliably) apply multiple formats to the contents of a form field; so I would alter this so that you are writing to a  or possibly to a set of s (one for each bit of format).
You can then just style it/them with normal CSS